# How to include CMake from a vcpkg port in a patch?

Tags: cmake, vcpkg

I have a lot of internal libraries that my specific team wants to migrate to vcpkg. My team is not as familiar with CMake as we probably should be, and I have had the most experience with it but am not an expert. As an added bonus, due to lacking a standard package manager in the past, there were a lot of CMake utility files that were shared between these libraries via hardcoded paths. I am trying to make this more modular with vcpkg but I have been struggling to share code outside of `portfile.cmake`, which makes me afraid that I cannot do this without either utilizing the hardcoded paths or duplicating the CMake in each port.

My goal is to use some form of `include(name_of_script.cmake)` or similar to utilize these files. I have followed the [Authoring Script Ports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcpkg/maintainers/authoring-script-ports) guide but am not sure that is the right way to go about this. Assuming a basic port like this:

`vcpkg.json`

```
    {
      "name": "cmake-utilities",
      "version": "1.0.0"
    }
```

`portfile.cmake`

```
file(INSTALL
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/some_utility.cmake"
    DESTINATION "${CURRENT_PACKAGES_DIR}/share/${PORT}")

set(VCPKG_POLICY_CMAKE_HELPER_PORT enabled)
```

and `some_utility.cmake`

```
function(some_utility)
  message("something useful")
endfunction()
```

I can depend on `cmake-utilities` in another port, and call `some_utility()` in that port's `portfile.cmake`, but from there I have been unable to determine a way to include the script in that port's `CMakeLists.txt` via a patch, which is where I need these utilities. Am I going about this wrong, or is this just not a feature of vcpkg?